# How can I interrupt method execution by time?

Tags: java

Suppose method `A` is calling method `B`. Can method `A` control execution time of method `B` and interrupt it in, suppose, 60 seconds (method `B` can hangs for example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run tasks asynchronously using an `ExecutorService`, obtaining a `Future` that enables you to get the result of the task when it is done. There's a `get` method on the `Future` that you can call to wait for the answer, with a timeout. If it times out, you try to cancel the task by calling `cancel` on the `Future`.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// Callable that has a run() method that executes the task
Callable<String> callable = ...;

// Submit the task for execution
Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callable);

try {
    String result = future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("Timeout");
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

There's a lot more to the concurrency API, see the package `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe what exactly do you want?
Just stopping of execution method you can use `return, System.exit()`, last stop VM. 
By time, just check time and return from method. Also, you can try some reflection hacks...
By the way, these are just a imagination if you will describe in more words what do you need I will help you.

Comment: For this description answer NO if two methods in one thread and YES if B it is a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void wait(int n){
    long time0,time1;
     time0=System.currentTimeMillis();
    do{
        time1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    while (time1-time0<n);
```

}

I think that works. If you invoke this method, pass it with the amount of time in milliseconds you want the program to wait as parameter.

Good luck!